# Apex test for batch

Tags: unit-test, batch

I am writing test class for two batch classes, `X` and `Y`.I executed batch `X` from one test method between `test.starttest` and `test.stoptest`.This works fine.

**Issue:**

- The issue is I'm inserting few records in X that I need in Y.
- This is happening through two different buttons from user side.
- Now if I execute both batch is same `test.starttest` and `test.stoptest`, i couldn't get the batch `X` done because its async process.
- If I execute batch `Y` from other `testmethod` in test class, I'm unable to get the values inserted in batch `X` from previous test method.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Batch x will execute when your method hits `test.stopTest()`. Have you tried validating your data after that happens?

Comment: Yes. Batch X will be finished at test.stoptest(). I cheked my data at that point. Its getting inserted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short Answer:**

Try calling both `Batch X` and `Batch Y` within the same `testMethod` and perform assert after `stopTest`.

**Long Answer:**

Here you are testing two batches `X` and `Y`.

**Limitations:**

- We cannot call Test.stopTest more than once in a Test class
- Without the stopTest call, asynchronous jobs will not run

### Current Testing methodology:

```
Test Data Generation -> Call Batch X -> Call Batch Y -> StopTest and Assert -> End the test
```

### Recommended Testing methodology:

**Batch X test**

```
Test 1 Data Generation -> Call Batch X  -> StopTest and Assert -> End the test
```

**Batch Y test**

```
Test 2 Stub the resultant data of Batch X -> Call Batch Y  -> StopTest and Assert -> End the test
```

**Pros:**

- So by this you don't really rely on execution of Batch X, instead you have stubbed the data which would exactly mimic the effect of Batch X execution.
- Introducing stubbed data makes your tests independent and also makes your input and output rigid.
- In future if the Batch Z calls the Batch Y at end of its execution, you don't need to assert the every new possible flow again, since Batch Y specifies its own set of [Pre-Conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract)
- You will be able to test individual components to the fullest granularity, and any breaking implementation changes in Batch X will not raise false assertion failures for Batch Y since both the tests are decoupled

**Reference on Async Batch limitations:**

> The System.schedule method starts an asynchronous process. This means
>   that when you test scheduled Apex, you must ensure that the scheduled
>   job is finished before testing against the results. Use the Test
>   methods startTest and stopTest around the System.schedule method to
>   ensure it finishes before continuing your test. All asynchronous calls
>   made after the startTest method are collected by the system. When
>   stopTest is executed, all asynchronous processes are run
>   synchronously. If you don’t include the System.schedule method within
>   the startTest and stopTest methods, the scheduled job executes at the
>   end of your test method for Apex saved using Salesforce.com API
>   version 25.0 and later, but not in earlier versions.

https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/14550/3672

Comment: Thankyou kathik,  my first batch is executed fine from test class.  Issue is, i need date inserted in first batch for executong second batch. I am executing second batch from other test method. So am unable to get results inserted in first test method from batch.

Comment: @AnuragA I updated the answer. Please let me know your thoughts